# Conversion of dosage based on body weight

Tags: algebra-precalculus, unit-of-measure

Infant ibuprofen containes 100mg/5.0mL suspension. The recommended dose is 10mg/kg body to weight. How many mL of this suspension should be given to an infant weighing 18 lb?

**That's not a serious question. Don't take that or the answer as advice. I am not responsible for anything bad can happen.**

Comment: I would like to ask why there's a 'chemistry' tag in math.stackexchange? o.O

Comment: @Noxob Please migrate this question to the chemistry.stackexchange as it is only partly mathematical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$18$ lb $\approx$ $8.16$ kg

$10$ mg per $1$ kg gives $81.6$ mg per $8.16$ kg.

Per $100$ mg, there is $5$ mL, so per $81.6$ mg there is $\dfrac{81.6}{20}=4.08$ mL of suspension.

Answer (score 1):

The child weighs 8.18kg.

So at 10mg per kg thats 81.8mg for a dose...

The suspension holds 100mg for every 5mL, so *give about 4mL*

I am *not* responsible if something bad happens. *Note that 4mL (4 millilitres)  is not very much at all*.

Comment: Your caution note made my wonder if the asker is about to actually give a baby some ibuprofen. If so, Noxob, *please* don't take advice about potential toxins from strangers on the internet.

Comment: It's not a serious problem. It's just an example... I'll edit my post

Comment: OK good, thought it might be some kind of maths that actually matters for once.